# How to properly use Laravel Service Container?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-service-container

Ok, I've watched the Laracast videos on the topic and also have read the documentation, still I miss the core point here. Let's say we have the following structure:

[image]

So I understood how to create a service provider, bind a class to the service container and resolve it later. But what if `MyCustomClass` binding has to be replaced let's say by `\App\SomeOtherClass`. That would lead to an exception of missing `SomeOtherClass` if I don't reference it. This leads me to the question: "What's the point of using service container, since I still have to reference the bound class again? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind to an interface/contract which both of the swappable classes conform to.

```
interface CustomInterface
{
    public function greeting();
}

class FirstCustomClass implements CustomInterface
{
    public function greeting()
    {
        return 'hello world';
    }
}

class SecondCustomClass implements CustomInterface
{
    public function greeting()
    {
        return 'hello world two';
    }
}
```

Then in your service provider bind to `Namespace\Of\My\Interface\CustomInterface:class` and then return which ever implementation you want.

Inside of your controller you should dependency inject your Interface, which will then end up giving you the default class.

**This then means that you can quickly swap a class for another that has the same interface, or mock it easily when testing.**

Comment: Edited it like this : https://ibb.co/f5k4BF  and it's working . Now I only change the bound class in "register" method and it gives the desired output . Thanks .